# Docker nginx connection refused (port 80 and 443) when using corporate signed certificate

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl

I am running nginx as a reverse proxy in a docker environment.
the follwing is the Dockerfile used to create the instance.

```
FROM nginx:1.18.0

ENV https_proxy=http://someproxy.nt.gov.au:8080
ENV http_proxy=http://someproxy.nt.gov.au:8080
RUN env

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY server-chain.cert /etc/nginx/server.cert
COPY server-chain.key /etc/nginx/server.key
COPY /html /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN echo 'alias ll="ls -la"' >> ~/.bashrc
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

STOPSIGNAL SIGQUIT


CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

the following is the upstream directive and the server {} section of the nginx.conf file - the rest is default

```
upstream cics-liberty {
      server some-app-server:3000 ;
      }
```

and

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;
    ssl_certificate server.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key server.key;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /offtocics/ {
      proxy_pass http://cics-liberty ;
     }
    location /barcode/ {
      proxy_pass http://cics-liberty ;
     }
    location /birt_wlp_s1/ {
      proxy_pass http://cics-liberty ;
     }
    location /scope2/ {
      proxy_pass http://cics-liberty ;
     }
...
}
```

the docker command to instantiate the server is

```
docker run -it --name webserver -d -p 8047:80 -p 8046:443 webserver:0.1
```

i am running 2 of these instances, one using a self signed certificate. the other has a certificate bundle signed by our corporate CA.

the server using the self signed certificate behaves as expected.
the server using the certificates signed by the corporate CA refuses connections on both the **http and the https** ports.

the logging output from both is the same, other than the sever refusing connections has nothing in the access log.  it looks like it is being refused even before it gets to the webserver.

The docker environment does not have any firewalls in its internal virtual network

I have rebuilt the failing webserver with the self signed certificates and it works as expected.

Comment: I see you're using the environment variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`. I don't believe nginx supports this. https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1399

Comment: Sometimes nginx will print errors about SSL to the error log. Have you checked the error log?

Comment: First check if ports 80, 443 are free in your linux machine. `fuser 80/tcp` and `fuser 443/tcp`. If they return sth, that means those ports are busy.

Answer (score 0):

This was a configuration error on my part.
I reformatted the certificate bundle from PCKS7 to PEM format, however i did not decrypt the associated private key.

once i installed the decrypted version of the private key - all ok.